# chartjs stack bar graph color not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, chart.js

i am trying to change default colors picked by stacked bar graph in chart.js and below is my code. i still see it is not picking up my defined colors

```
  <div style="display: block">
                        <canvas baseChart
                                [datasets]="barChartData"
                                [labels]="barChartLabels"
                                [options]="barChartOptions"
                                [legend]="barChartLegend"
                                [chartType]="barChartType"></canvas>
                    </div>
```

.ts

```
      public barChartOptions:any = {
        scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }]
            }
      };

      public barChartLabels:string[] = ['01/27', '01/29', '01/31', '02/01', '02/03', '02/05', '02/07'];
      public barChartType:string = 'bar';
      public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

    public barChartColors:string[] = ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)','#9CC463','#E65E72','#F2A950','#A9559A','#42B6CD']
  public barChartData:any[] = [
    {data: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], label: 'Email Clicks', backgroundColor: this.barChartColors},
    {data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], label: 'External Activites', backgroundColor: this.barChartColors},
    {data: [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 8, 0], label: 'Form Submissions', backgroundColor:this.barChartColors},
    {data: [1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1], label: 'Email Sends', backgroundColor:this.barChartColors},
    {data: [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 13, 0], label: 'Web Page Visits', backgroundColor:this.barChartColors},
    {data: [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], label: 'Email Opens', backgroundColor:this.barChartColors}
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Each data point needs a background color:

e.g.

`{data: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], label: 'Email Clicks', backgroundColor:[rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0)]'}`

If you intend to use the same color for each data point, you can just create the array dynamically instead of all that copy and paste.

Comment: see the edited answer. it does not work either for me

Answer (score 0):

Is this ng2-charts?

add this to the canvas tag:

`[colors]="barChartColors"`

Each element in the barChartColors maps to the same index as an entry in barChartData

You don't need to put backgroundColor in each barChartData then.

Comment: doing this wipes all the colors